# Nuget restore doesn't work in project

Tags: nuget

So I've tried everything that was advised such has updating Nuget, ticking nuget.org in Nuget Packege manager and I still get the error of:
[image]

Does anybody know what to do ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your project path is long enough that when the package is restore, restore the package folder fails because it reached the qualified name length limit. See the [NuGet issue](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4311) for this.
Could you try to move you project to root drive?

Answer (score 1):

Move your project to a shorter path location (a root drive will be much better; Example: D:\) and have a try.